# List comprehension in haskell, String -> [String], empty characters not being removed

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to split a string in to a list of characters and removing any non-letters in the process. Here is my code so far:

```
getCharList :: String -> [String] 
getCharList x = [filter isLetter c | c <- splitOn "" x, c /= ""]
```

The output I receive from, for example:

> getCharList "Why doesn't this work"

is:

> ["W","h","y","","d","o","e","s","n","","t","","t","h","i","s","","w","o","r","k"]

Could someone please explain why this doesn't seem to be able to remove the empty characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your direct question: I will simply point out that `filter isLetter c` may be the empty list even when `c` is not the empty list; hence `c /= ""` does not ensure `filter isLetter c /= ""`.

Popping up a level, I find your existing code to have a few oddities. The main thing you should realize is that `String` is *exactly the same type as* `[Char]` (it is just another name for it). There's no need to do any processing to convert a `String` into a list of its elements -- `splitOn ""` is basically unneeded work. The literal `"foo"` is just shorthand for the literal `['f', 'o', 'o']` (try them both in ghci!). I therefore propose a complete rewrite of your function, along the following lines:

```
getLetters :: String -> [Char]
getLetters = filter isLetter
```

(I used `[Char]` instead of `String` in the return type to emphasize that I intend to think of the returned thing as a list of letters rather than as a reasonable string. This is a human-level difference only; GHC would be just as happy to call the returned value a `String`.) This is perfectly idiomatic. If you prefer, you can also include the argument, writing instead:

```
getLetters s = filter isLetter s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the explanation really helped me.